# What is the negative form of "As soon as I saw her, I recognized her"?

Tags: negation, sentence-meaning, negative-polarity-items

Whether "No sooner had I seen her than I recognized her" is equivalent to the expression " As soon as I saw her, I recognized her" or " As soon as I had seen her, I recognized her." Would you mind explaining a bit more clearly?

Would "I didn't recognize her until I saw her" equate the expression in meaning "No sooner had I seen her than I recognized her"?

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/inversion
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_sentence

Comment: *No sooner had I seen her, I recognized her* is not idiomatic, but *As soon as I saw her, I recognized her* is perfectly okay (except I bet that almost all native speakers would almost always put the main clause *first*). Although it's syntactically valid, it's hard to imagine a context where *I didn't recognize her until I **saw her*** (not "see her") would make sense (it's not usually *possible* to recognize someone unless you can ***see*** them). So what exactly is the situation where you think you want to say something like that?

Comment: What do you intend for the negative to mean? That you didn't recognize her at all, or just that you didn't recognize her *immediately*?

Comment: (Also: I assume you mean "statements," since the sentence you provide is not a question.)

Comment: "No sooner had X happened _than_ Y happened" means the _same_ as "As soon as X happened, Y happened."

Comment: Yes. _sooner_ is a comparative, and comparatives require (and are marked by) **_than_**.

Comment: You need to state what you mean by "negative": "I didn't recognize her until I see her" is not the negative or converse of "No sooner had I seen her, I recognized her."

Comment: Why close this? It’s common in questions to assume that English functions like math in creating negatives, and here’s an up-voted generic answer from a genuine linguist. Let’s reopen and make it available to others.

Answer (score 5):

There are two clauses, separated by a comma, in

- *As soon as I saw her, I recognized her.*

The second clause is the main clause. The negative of the main clause is

- **As soon as I saw her, I didn't recognize her*

which makes no sense, because not recognizing someone is not an activity that happens suddenly, and that's the meaning of *as soon as*.

But the first clause can also be negated.

- **As soon as I didn't see her, I recognized her*

which also makes no sense; neither does

- **As soon as I didn't see her, I didn't recognize her*

So, as is normally the case, the example sentence doesn't **have** any "negative form" (let alone "**the** negative form"), at least not one that's grammatical and means something understandable.

Sometimes people have been taught (ironically, in what's called "grammar school") that negative is something you do to a sentence, like "passive". Unfortunately, [negation](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) is **much** more complex than that.

Comment: I disagree re this: As soon as I saw the woman, I didn't recognize her [from before].

Comment: _As soon as I saw the woman, I realized I didn't recognize her_ Realizing can be instantaneous, but not its negation.

Comment: Would hardly/ scarcely/ rarely  be an equivalent expression to " No sooner had I seen her, I recognized her"?   What's the difference between "No sooner had I seen her, I recognized her" and " No sooner did I see her, I recognized her"?  In which situation each one of these expressions are in use.

Comment: As you can see on [the list of negatives](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), _hardly, scarcely, rarely,_ and _seldom_ are negative triggers. So are questions (yes/no and _wh_-), equatives, comparatives, superlatives, and hypothetical clauses. They all license NPIs, though not always the same ones.

Comment: Why do usually negative adverbial reverse the sentence pattern in English?  For instance, Hardly had I ever been to Church before. What other negative adverbials would you like to list that inverses the structures and why it is necessary to do that ?

Comment: Many pieces of English grammar are sensitive to negation. It's one of the great human signifiers. No animal has any negation, but all human languages use it. If you're having trouble with a sentence, look and see if it's got a negative in it and try it without the negative. Or put one in if there isn't one already. In particular, Adverb Fronting is an NPI, and tag questions respond to any negative.